# Как установить прежнее значение ячейки

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, помогите пожалуйста в решении проблемы. Идея такая: Есть табличка со значениями, кликнув дважды по ячейки превращаю ее в *INPUT*, а как сделать чтобы значение ячейки появлялось в "инпуте".

Вот моя функция которая делает преобразование и по идее должна отобразить значение ячейки в "инпуте":

```
function convertToInput() {
    $('td.editable').on('dblclick', function(){
        $(this).html(function() {
            var input = '<input type="text" name="fname" />';
            var textEditable = $('td.editable');
            return input + textEditable;
        });
    });
    $('td.editable').keypress(function(event) {
        if ( event.which == 13 ) {
            $(this).html('<td class="editable"></td>');
        }
    });
}
```

вот экранный снимок того что получается:

[image]

Comment: @thunder, @lampa, @Zhukov Roman, @eicto, поучавствуйте пожалуйста в ответе!

Comment: да, че-то расслабились все. ну-ка, бегом!

Comment: @Артёмыч большинство ответов легкой и средней сложности. Некоторые просто не хотят на такие отвечать, т.к. не интересно. Другие - отвечают по тем или иным причинам. Ограничивать себя несколькими участниками как-то не уважительно к другим)

Comment: @lampa я понял, учту...

Answer (score 5):

Наверное надо взять значение:

```
....
var val = $(this).text();
...
```

А потом наверное в <input value='+val+'>. Как-то так. Не хочу развёрнуто писать, хочу увидеть работу Вашей мысли...

Answer (score 3):

вот мой вариант [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_K88/2p739/) На ваш вопрос я ответил?.. Но тут собственно я сам задумался а как их эти ячейки редактировать, чтобы предыдущая ячейка удаляла инпут и сохраняла значение value в td? Please help

Comment: Извените что отвечаю вопросом на вопрос

Comment: в переменной храните ссылку на `<td>` в котором происходит редактирование, в обработчике клика завершайте редактирование
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2p739/3/

Answer (score 1):

Коллеги, предлагаю [свой](http://jsfiddle.net/dcgrB/1/) вариант решения.

Comment: пара недочетов:

* два раза по одной и той же ячейке кликните двойным, будет пусто в input'е. 
* сначала по одной ячейке, потом по другой. будет два input'а.

Comment: на счет первого согласен, а на счет второго можно и по третьему щелкнуть и по четвертому, что здесь не так, что не работает? Тут уже все зависит от реализации, кому как надо.

Comment: не работает принцип inplace editing. input должен быть только на время редактирования. на blur вы же его гасите? в качестве черновика вариант нормальный, но далеко не полный, именно недочеты, не ошибки.